# Is it safe to feed my pet lizard a molting cricket?

Tags: feeding, crickets, molting

I have bought a number of feeder crickets, several of which are in stages of molting.

1. Is it safe to feed a cricket mid-molting to a pet lizard?
2. Should I discard the molted husk left behind, or is it safe to try and feed it to my lizard as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I want to create an account just to read it, but someone apparently did a test on a large species of cricket to see what the molted shell was composed of: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/30155359?sid=21104892013541&uid=3739256&uid=3739656&uid=2&uid=4

Comment: When not molting, the shell is on the cricket too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cricket sheds the husk prior to feeding just throw it out. If you think about it, when they eat them in the wild they don't have any humans around to shed the husks for them. They surely eat them regardless. It won't hurt your lizard.